# The Realm of Exchange War, Episode 1: The murder that started it all

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The Realm of Exchange, also known as the Realm of Questions and Answers, is divised in many little states. Some of these famous states, and the ones which will interest us today, are [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) and [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). Every people living there, known as the "Users", are free to travel through these lands and to ask or answer questions, as long as they follow the rules of these states. So every citizen of the Realm of Exchange can get the citizenship of different of these states.

The realm was living beautiful years of peace, until one day when the 4 states mentioned above started a bloody war, because one of their citizen had been killed, and each state started to blame the others for this crime.

You are a citizen of the Realm of Exchange and of the state of Puzzling. You made it your mission to solve this mystery and to bring back peace on the realm of Exchange. The first step for you is to try to figure who has been killed. One of the other inhabitant of Puzzling seems to know who that person is, but refuses to give you the information directly. You totally understand, as a good citizen of Puzzling wouldn't share a good information without hiding it in a puzzle before.

The man gave you a piece of paper where was written the following message:

> 0006564005755903202323754895

With just this information, will you be able to find out who has been killed?

*(Disclaimers: This set of questions is obviously made in the purpose of fun and puzzles. If anyone used as a character in these questions feel offended by this puzzle, do not hesitate to tell me so.)*

Comment: I highly recommend asking permission before using someone in a puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi Sure. Is there any way I can directly contact one of the users through the site though? Well else I will just base the rest of the story on things which doesn't involve members.

Comment: Most people don't publish their contact information in their profiles, but if they *do*, you can use that. You could also ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) - a lot of our chat regulars would be happy to be "cast" as whatever character you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer:

> If we split the number into four equal parts, we get 0006564 0057559 0320232 3754895. These are question ids from the four SE sites mentioned, respectively: [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/are-there-any-boat-tours-for-lake-baikal), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57559/what-would-cause-life-forms-to-be-water-soluble-i-e-witches), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320232/what-is-the-missile-silo-and-how-do-i-power-it) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754895/how-to-remove-text-above-jslider).
>  The Travel, WB and SO questions were asked by user z -, while the Arqade question was asked by user l i *who is the same as user z -* <s>. This could indicate that z is the one who died, but why the different Arqade asker?
>  Maybe the letters from their usernames need to arranged to solve a further cypher, but I can't make sense of "zzl iz"</s>

I guess it's

> [user z -](https://stackexchange.com/users/17205/z?tab=accounts) then

Comment: The other user confirms. You found the victim!